# How to create a form for insert and update action for related model in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, insert, relation

I have two models: `S`, `Sp`. In the `Sp` model, there is a `hasOne()` relation with `S`.

In the `SpController` I have two actions, `insert` and `update`, as follow:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Sp();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

and

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

In the `sp/views/_form.php` I have a field that related to `S`, like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model->s, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

It works fine in update action because of relation, but it throws an error which not exist `s` on `<?= $form->field($model->s, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>` in create action.

How to bind `name` field in the create action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use model from relation in this way, you need to manually create it. Don't forget to actually save data from `S` model.

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Sp();
    $model->populateRelation('s', new S());

    if (
        $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()
        && $model->s->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->s->validate()
    ) {
        $model->s->save();
        $model->s_id = $model->s->id;
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

But you should really consider creating dedicated form model instead of using Active Record directly. It will make view and controller much simpler.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I've already done  `$model->s = new S();` but it throws an error: `Setting read-only property: backend\models\SP::s`

Answer (score 1):

I think a proper way to achieve your goal is to create a FormModel having all the attributes you need (in this case 'name' of the S object), and use it in the view, something like:

`$form->field($formModel, 'sName')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>`